# Docker-compose links to service from different file

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have three docker services.

1. MySql
2. PhpMyAdmin
3. MyWebApp

Obviously `MyWebApp` service will link to `MySql` for database connection. I can write all three services in a single file like this. And it works just fine.

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mywebapp:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - "7100:3000"
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    environment:
      DB_HOST: 'mysql'
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: ''
      DB_PASSWORD: ''
      DB_NAME: 'mynet_prod'
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - mynet

  mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ''
      MYSQL_USER: ''
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
      - mynet-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mynet
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-pXXX"]
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - 7010:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: ""
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    networks:
      - mynet


networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mynet-mysql:
    driver: local
  mynet-redis:
    driver: local
```

Now, the problem is, if I have to update `mywebapp`, I will have to down all the services with `docker-compose down` and then up again with `docker-compose up` which creates some overhead as I almost never make any changes to `mysql` or `phpmyadmin` and they takes a significantly long time to boot. Also, if there were more than one services that depends on MySQL, putting them all in one file causes downtime to all of them each time I have to make a change to a single service.

Hence, I was thinking to move the `mysql` and `phpmyadmin` into a separate file and `mywebapp` into another.

`docker-compose-db.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:

  mysql:
    image: 'mysql/mysql-server:8.0'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ''
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ''
      MYSQL_USER: ''
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 1
    volumes:
      - mynet-mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - mynet
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-pXXX"]
      retries: 3
      timeout: 5s

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    ports:
      - 7010:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: ""
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
      PMA_HOST: mysql
    networks:
      - mynet


networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  mynet-mysql:
    driver: local
  mynet-redis:
    driver: local
```

`docker-compose-webapp.yaml`

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  mywebapp:
    image: ...
    ports:
      - "7100:3000"
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
    environment:
      DB_HOST: 'mysql'
      DB_PORT: 3306
      DB_USER: ''
      DB_PASSWORD: ''
      DB_NAME: 'mynet_prod'
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - mynet

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

Then I ran `docker-compose -f docker-compose-db.yaml up` and it worked. But when I tried to boot up the webapp with `docker-compose -f docker-compose-webapp.yaml up`, it gave me the following error

`Service 'mywebapp' depends on service 'mysql' which is undefined.`

Obviously, docker is trying to resolve the `mysql` link but since it's defined in another file, it's considered as undefined. Is there a way to import definitions from another file or just another better way to resolve this kind of situation?

Comment: Typically you'd just volume mount your web app's source code (assuming it's interpreted and not compiled ala PHP) so you can make changes without restarting the container. Otherwise, you can remove the `links` and `depends_on` and just join the same network to have them connect

Comment: I typically use docker images as it saves me from repetitive work. For instance, if your composer-dependencies changes, you will have to log in to your server and run install again. The same goes for new folder permission adjustment and a lot of things.

This is why I prefer a dockerfile with an automated build thanks to Github actions. All I have to do is to update the image version from my server and restart the compose file.

Comment: Right, sorry. I had assumed you were talking about local development.

Comment: Have you seen the documentation for [deploying changes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/production/#deploying-changes)... `docker compose up --no-deps webapp`

Comment: You shouldn't need `docker-compose down`, which might simplify your setup.  If you're working with self-contained Docker images, it should be enough to run `docker-compose build; docker-compose up -d` to rebuild images and then restart containers with updated images.  (I'd recommend against using a volume mount for your source code, preferring an ordinary non-Docker development environment for day-to-day work; there's also potential for your local code diverging from the built image if you're talking about a deployment path.)